# WebRTC: What is RTPFragmentationHeader in encoder implementation?

Tags: video, video-streaming, webrtc, h.264, openh264

I have modified `h264_encoder_impl` to use nvidia grid based hardware encoder. This is done by replacing OpenH264 specific calls with Nvidia API calls. Encoded stream can be written to file successfully but writing `_buffer` and `_size` of `encoded_image_` are not enough and `RTPFragmentationHeader` also needs to be filled.

```cpp
// RtpFragmentize(EncodedImage* encoded_image,
//                       std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>* encoded_image_buffer,
//                       const VideoFrameBuffer& frame_buffer,
//                       SFrameBSInfo* info,
//                      RTPFragmentationHeader* frag_header)

// encode
openh264_->Encode(input, &info /*out*/);

// fragmentize ?
RtpFragmentize(&encoded_image_ /*out*/, &encoded_image_buffer_, *frame_buffer, 
               &info, &frag_header /*out*/); 

// ...

// send 
encoded_image_callback_->OnEncodedImage(encoded_image_, &codec_specific, &frag_header);
```

Current Openh264 based implementation fills `frag_header` in `RTPFragmentize()` and VP8 fills it differently. I can see something with NAL untis and layers which also calculates `encoded_image->_length` but I have no idea how.

I can not find any documentation on it anywhere. VP8 and OpenH264 implementations is all I have.

So what is `RTPFragmentationHeader`? what does it do? What is `encoded_image->_length`? How to fill it correctly when using custom H264 encoder? I can find startcode but what next? How to fill all its members?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After going through `RTPFragmentize()` in `h264_encoder_impl` I have figured it out.

In an encoded frame there are multiple NALUs. There are different NALUs including AUD, SPS (67), PPS (68) and IDR. Each NALU is separated by the 4 byte start code which is `00 00 00 01`.

For OpenH264, header looked like this for the first frame

```
[00 00 00 01 67 42 c0 20 8c 8d 40 20 03 09 00 f0  
 88 46 a0 00 00 00 01 68 ce 3c 80]00 00 00 01 ..
```

You can see start code in bold. Only bytes between square brackets belong to header, last start code is for frame data.

`RTPFragmentationHeader` for above:

```
frag_header->fragmentationVectorSize = 3     // 2 fragments for header
                                             // 3rd fragment for frame buffer

frag_header->fragmentationOffset[0]  = 4     
frag_header->fragmentationLength[0]  = 15

frag_header->fragmentationOffset[1]  = 23    // 4 + 15 + sizeof(startcode)
frag_header->fragmentationLength[1]  = 4    

frag_header->fragmentationOffset[2]  = 31   
frag_header->fragmentationLength[2]  = 43218 // last fragment is frame buffer
```

Next frames always had only one fragment which looked like following

```
00 00 00 01 67 b8 .. .. ..
```

`encoded_image->_length` is the size of actual encoded frame buffer and
`encoded_image->_size` is maximum size of an encoded frame buffer.

OpenH264 API gives number of NALUs in encoded frame which is used to calculate fragments while the API I was using only provided header and its size no matter if header is actually added with frame or not. Searching frame bytes only for size of header allowed correct calculation of fragmentation.

Doing this finally sent the encoded data and it was decoded correctly on client browser.

**Update:** In essence, I had to skip `RTPFragmentize()` entirely, because it is made specifically for OpenH264, and calculate `frag_header` myself based on above observations.